# I'm writing a shell in C and I am having trouble with pointers to char arrays in a struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct, fork

When I run my code the first `printParams()` call works perfectly. But every call after `fork()` the `struct` loses all of its `char` array values. I'm not that knowledgeable of pointers, but I can tell that the root of this problem is probably pointer-based. For example, the first `printParams()` will print out all of the values assigned in the `Parse()` function. But after the `fork()`, all of the integer values such as `background` and `argumentCount` are displayed but none of the string values associated with `inputRedirect` or the string values held in the `vectorArguments` array.

![Here is a photo of my output]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHUPw.png)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "parse.h"

void printParams(Param_t * param);

struct PARAM
{
    char *inputRedirect;           /* file name or NULL */
    char *outputRedirect;          /* file name or NULL */
    int background;                /* ethier 0 (false) or 1 (true) */
    int argumentCount;             /* number of tokens in argument vector 
    */
    char *argumentVector[MAXARGS]; /* array of String */
};

typedef struct PARAM Param_t;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int i;
    int debug;
    pid_t pid;
    
    if(argc>1){
        if(!strcmp(argv[1], "-debug"))
            debug = 1;
    }
   
    Param_t * testParam = Parse();
    
    if(debug == 1){
        printParams(testParam);
    }

    pid = fork();       
    printParams(testParam);
    
    if(pid == 0){
        exit(1);
    }       
    return 0;
}

void printParams(Param_t *param)
{
    int i;
    
    printf("InputRedirect: [%s]\n", (param->inputRedirect != NULL) ? param-
    >inputRedirect: "NULL");
    printf("OutputRedirect: [%s]\n", (param->outputRedirect != NULL) ? 
    param->outputRedirect: "NULL");
    printf ("Background: [%d]\n", param->background);
    printf ("ArgumentCount: [%d]\n", param->argumentCount);
    
    for (i = 0; i < param->argumentCount; i++)
        printf("ArgumentVector[%2d]: [%s]\n", i, param->argumentVector[i]);     
}

Param_t* Parse(){
    char *toke[MAXARGS];
    int i = 0;
    char str[MAXSTRLENGTH];
    int j;
    int k=0;
    
    Param_t* testParam = malloc(sizeof(Param_t));
    testParam->argumentCount = 0;
    
    printf("Enter your commands:\n");
    fgets(str, MAXSTRLENGTH, stdin);
    
    toke[i] = strtok(str, " ");

    //Tokenizes the user input into the toke array
    while(toke[i] != NULL){
        //printf("%s\n", toke[i]);
        ++i;
        toke[i] = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
    
    i=0;  
    char c;
    
    while(toke[i] != NULL){
        c = toke[i][0];
        if(c == '<')
        {
            for(j=0; j<strlen(toke[i]); ++j ){
                toke[i][j] = toke[i][j+1];
            }
            testParam->inputRedirect = toke[i];
        }
        else if(c == '>')
        {
            for(j=0; j<strlen(toke[i]); ++j ){
                toke[i][j] = toke[i][j+1];
            }
            testParam->outputRedirect = toke[i];
        }
        else if(c == '&')
        {
            testParam->background = 1;
            //background  
        }
        else
        {
            testParam->argumentVector[k] = toke[i];
            k++;
            //save as cmd vector
        }
        ++i;
    }   
    testParam->argumentCount = k;
    return testParam;
}
```

Comment: If you cut down your code to the smallest size that exhibits the problem you'll get better help

Comment: btw what's the content of parse.h?

Comment: A pointer *just points* somewhere, it *does not hold* the data pointed to.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you loose all `char *` values is because `strtok()` function doesn't create buffer. Basically all your `char*` consist of an address pointing into `str` variable you read with `fgets()`. The `str` variable has scope only to end of `Parse()` function.

Solution for this:

Replace:

```
testParam->inputRedirect = toke[i];
```

with:

```
testParam->inputRedirect = malloc(MAXSTRLENGTH);
memset( testParam->inputRedirect, 0, MAXSTRLENGTH);
memcpy( testParam->inputRedirect, toke[i], strlen(toke[i]) );
```

But please note, that this leads to memory leak since there is no `free()`.

Sugestion:

Create static instance of structure in `main` and give its pointer to `Parse` function.

```
Param_t testParam;
Parse( &testParam );
```

Let the `Parse` function fill it. And at the end of `main` call free for all `char *` buffers inside `testParam`

Comment: Why not just use `strcpy()` instead of `memset/memcpy`?